# Error when trying to merge accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

Can anyone help me merge this old [unregistered account](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/users/254742/man) of mine with my current [official one](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/users/258247/nicco)? When I tried merging them, it says "e-mail address is invalid":

> [image]

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Where and how exactly did you try to merge the accounts?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: By using the Help Center

Comment: You mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7SF1.png)?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard:yes that's what I mean

Comment: Well, reproduced with "dummy@secret" which is obviously invalid... your email is probably something non-standard as well, try creating Google account, then you'll have standard gmail address you can add to your logins in this account of yours, and use it in the contact form.